# Odoo 10: Error: "You must set a Vendor Location for this partner" in internal purchase orders in multi-company setup

Tags: odoo-10, purchase-order

I encounter an error in **internal** purchase orders between the two companies in a **multi-company setup**. When I try to accept a purchase order I get the **ERROR: "You must set a Vendor Location for this partner"** and the purchase order remains a draft (RFQ). However all other purchase and all sales orders work properly! Let me explain in more detail:

**Company A:** the initial company configured before enabling the multi-company option

**Company B:** the second internal company configured **after enabling the multi-company option**

**Company C:** external customer or supplier

**Only the purchase orders with company A as supplier and company B as customer fail** with the error, all other purchase and sales orders work!

That means:

- The reverse with company B as supplier and company A as customer works
- All purchase orders with an external company C work (for both companies A and B)
- All sales orders work with all possible customer/supplier combinations (A-B, B-A, A-C, B-C)

I tried to carefully review the storage locations but can not make out any difference between company A and company B.

Questions:

- Does anyone have an idea what could be wrong or what setting I could try to change?
- How could I try to isolate the error?
- Could someone be so kind telling me how I can try to help myself? Where can I see or enable error logs? Where can I see more detailed output or parameters to try to understand what is triggering the error.
- Purchase and sales orders had been carried out for company A before enabling the multi-company option. Could this be the cause? Do I need to start with a fresh empty database (no previous orders), when enabling the multi-company option?

Any help or hints would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we are work with multi company and company partner as suppler or customer then we must do location configuration in partner.

In **purchase order** creating process, when picking is creating then system is setting **location_id** based on **property_stock_supplier** field.

In **Sales Order** creating process, when picking is creating then system is setting **location_id** based on **property_stock_customer** field.

[image]

This may help you.

Comment: Thank you especially for attaching the screenshot! This helped me to understand that it is necessary to **activate developer mode** for the **Warehouse settings to be shown** in the vendor configuration! Both  locations were empty or wrong. After correcting everything works now!